# Why python if command doesnt work correctly?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@Bot.command()
async def kod(ctx,discordid):
    objects = Code.manager(db)
    code_list = list(objects.all())
    i = 1
    while i <= len(code_list):
        usercode = objects.get(i)
        usercode = usercode.__dict__
        id = usercode.get('discord_id')
        print(discordid)
        print(id)
        if discordid == id:
            await ctx.send("worked")
        i = i + 1
```

I have problem with if command.you can see the result of the print(id) and print(discordid) code here:

```
806114153915875378
806114153915875378
```

You can see that discordid and id are the same.
But

```
if discordid == id:
    await ctx.send("worked")
```

Code doesnt work correctly and bot doesnt send message.There isnt a error printed at terminal.

Comment: ```id``` is a *built-in function*. Don't use it. Check with other variable name

Comment: `id` is a keyword in python, I would use an other variable name, but I don't know if that's the problem here

Comment: Are the ids both strings? Perhaps there are (different) trailing spaces on the ids? Try `if discordid.strip() == id.strip():`

Comment: also worth trying out is adding a print statement inside the `if` block, before the `await ctx.send("worked")` to see if perhaps the if is working correctly, but the send not

Comment: Print `type(discordid)` and `type(id)` and see if they are actually the same. Or it could be because your loop is not running from 0 to `len(code_list)-1` both inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this program

```
if str(discordid) == str(id):
    await ctx.send("worked")
```